# What is the -d flag in apache rewrite rules?

Tags: apache

I have checked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

and

Here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

and I cannot figure out what the '-d' flag is for in apache rewrite rules.

*Ex snippet:* `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Can someone shine some light on me for this one please? Thank you for any and all explanations and answers! :-)

Comment: Read the [module documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which you can find by clicking on "module documentation"  at the link you posted.

Comment: Must have missed that one; thanks!

Comment: Why did this get another downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly this was a 'to close to the painting' kind of thing as I missed the flag in the documentation.

```
  -d
Is directory.
Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
```

:-)